# Cache expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

How can I control the cache expiration in asp.net? I use absolute expiration and the cache expires every 3 hours.
NOw I want to add a condition, so that only if the condition is true, the cache should expire at the  end of 3 hours. Else, if the condition is false , the cache should not expire.

Is there a way I can do this?

I am using the following format:

```
ctx.Cache.Insert("cachename", cacheValue, null,
                  DateTime.Now.AddHours(Int32.Parse(siteViewModel.ApplicationSettings["CacheDurationHours"])), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
                 System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
                 null
                 );
```

where the duration is 3 hours. So the cache expires automatically in 3 hours.  is there a way to control the expiration with a condition?

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
DateTime absoluteExpiration = condition ? 
                  DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(...) : 
                  Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration;
ctx.Cache.Insert(..., absoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, ...);
```

BTW [the MSDN description of the absoluteExpiration parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx) recommends using `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` to calculate the absolute expiration.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the cacheValue a delegate which checks the condition

```
ctx.Cache.Insert("cachename", () => condition? null : cacheValue, null,
    DateTime.Now.AddHours(
        Int32.Parse(siteViewModel.ApplicationSettings["CacheDurationHours"])),
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
    null
);
```

And then to retrieve it, you would use something along the lines of

```
var del = ctx.Cache["cachename"] as Func<CacheValueType>;
if (del != null) cacheValue = del();
```

Although an easier way is to use a static rather than the cache, and just a private date as expiration.